# How to use Icescrum with Dashing (widget)?

Tags: ruby, json, widget, jira, dashing

I am trying to create a widget on Dashing that will extract data from Icescrum and update a specific widget.

The thing is I found info on how to program jira, so i've been trying to mess around with it to make it work with icescrum, but with no luck.

I tried this one:

```
require "uri"
require "net/http"
require "json"



SCHEDULER.every '2s', :first_in => 0 do |job|
 uri = URI.parse("http://website.ca:8080/icescrum")
 http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
 req = Net::HTTP::Get.new("uri.request_uri")
 req.basic_auth username, password
 response = http.request(req)
 issuesinProgress = JSON.parse(response.body)["total"]  
 send_event('synergy', value: issuesinProgress)
end
```

but I got this error:

```
scheduler caught exception:
undefined local variable or method `username' for main:Object
/home/administrator/dashboard/jobs/sample.rb:27:in `block in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rufus-scheduler-2.0.24/lib/rufus/sc/jobs.rb:230:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rufus-scheduler-2.0.24/lib/rufus/sc/jobs.rb:230:in `trigger_block'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rufus-scheduler-2.0.24/lib/rufus/sc/jobs.rb:204:in `block in trigger'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rufus-scheduler-2.0.24/lib/rufus/sc/scheduler.rb:430:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rufus-scheduler-2.0.24/lib/rufus/sc/scheduler.rb:430:in `block in trigger_job'
```

Comment: What have to you done so far? Can you post your code?

Comment: As @ShaohaoLin says, please provide your effort to acomplish this, and show us the errors you have. Please read this [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i've updated the first post with the code

Comment: I've been changing some things around and this is the new error message that I'm getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I just used a cURL function to get the information. I'll leave it here if anyone else needs it.  It also sends the results to an xml file (if you don't want that then just remove the last part)

.rb file:

```
%x{curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -X POST --data "@filename.xml" -u username:password http://website.ca:8080/icescrum/ --output result.xml}
```

Remember to change these dummy names with your links:

- filename.xml
- username
- password
- website.ca:8080/icescrum/
- result.xml

**a complete set up of the widget is also available here :
https://github.com/Flash-Dash/Icescrum-widget**

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a line:

```
req.basic_auth username, password
```

It's expecting two variables, "username" and "password", but neither look to be defined in your code, here. If they aren't defined you'll get an error that looks an awful lot like what you're getting.

Comment: i also thought that. i have tried defining the values but with no luck. So i am using a different method. thank you!